# Proguard tells me 'Please correct the above warnings first.'. How to address references of external jars?

Tags: android, proguard, antbuilder

How can I address the warnings?

**Log says**

```
 [proguard] Note: duplicate definition of library class...
 ...
 [proguard] Note: there were 370 duplicate class definitions.
 [proguard] Initializing...
 [proguard] Warning: abc.cba..: can't find superclass or interface xyz.zyx....
 ...
 [proguard] Note: the configuration refers to the unknown class 'android.app.backup.BackupAgentHelper'...
 ...
 [proguard] Warning: library class android.content.IntentFilter depends on program class org.xmlpull.v1.XmlSerializer...
 ...
```

**proguard.cfg**

```
-optimizationpasses 5
-dontusemixedcaseclassnames
-dontskipnonpubliclibraryclasses
-dontpreverify
-verbose
-optimizations !code/simplification/arithmetic,!field/*,!class/merging/*

-keep public class * extends android.app.Activity
-keep public class * extends android.app.Application
-keep public class * extends android.app.Service
-keep public class * extends android.content.BroadcastReceiver
-keep public class * extends android.content.ContentProvider
-keep public class * extends android.app.backup.BackupAgentHelper
-keep public class * extends android.preference.Preference
-keep public class com.android.vending.licensing.ILicensingService
-keep public class !testAppH23.** { *; }

-keepclasseswithmembernames class * {
    native <methods>;
}

-keepclasseswithmembers class * {
    public <init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet);
}

-keepclasseswithmembers class * {
    public <init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, int);
}

-keepclassmembers class * extends android.app.Activity {
   public void *(android.view.View);
}

-keepclassmembers enum * {
    public static **[] values();
    public static ** valueOf(java.lang.String);
}

-keep class * implements android.os.Parcelable {
  public static final android.os.Parcelable$Creator *;
}
```

Here is the 
**Android Ant Build with Proguard Enabled console log. Please see the link**
[ant build console log](http://pastebin.com/7yyrqTj6)

**Here is my build.xml (basically its the android original ant script). Please see the link**
[TestAppH23 Android Ant Build With Proguard Enabled](http://pastebin.com/vHuNS4Ba)

**local.properties**

```
sdk.dir=C:\\androiddev\\android-sdk-windows
```

**build.properties**

```
proguard.config=proguard.cfg
key.store=testapph23-release.keystore
key.alias=alisname
key.store.password=storepassword
key.alias.password=aliaspassword
```

**default.properties**

```
target=android-7
```

My apology for long post. Any guidance on the right direction is appreciated.

**UPDATES1**
**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      package="testAppH23.activity"
      android:versionCode="1"
      android:versionName="1.0">
    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/home"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        >
        <activity
            android:name=".start.StartActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.Translucent"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:launchMode="singleTask"
            >
            <intent-filter>
                <action
                    android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"
                    >
                </action>
                <category
                    android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"
                    >
                </category>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        .....
        <service android:name="com.abc.myjar.papi.PIntentService"></service>

        <service android:name=".service.XyzService"></service>

    </application>


    <uses-library android:name="org.apache.http.entity"/>
    <uses-library android:name="org.apache.http.james.mime4j"/>

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission...."/>

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="7" />

</manifest>
```

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You have to reassure ProGuard that some suspicious constructs in the input jars are ok.

Your program code contains copies or better versions of Android runtime classes in the package org.xmlpull.v1. If that's ok:

```
-dontwarn org.xmlpull.v1.**
-dontnote org.xmlpull.v1.**
```

Your program code contains copies of Android runtime classes in org.apache.http. If that's ok:

```
-dontnote org.apache.http.**
```

Your program code in the package examples refers to AWT, which doesn't exist in Android. If that's ok:

```
-dontwarn java.awt.**
```

Your PostgreSQL driver refers to many javax classes that don't exist in Android. If that's ok:

```
-dontwarn org.postgresql.**
```

And so on...

Cfr. ProGuard manual > [Troubleshooting](http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/troubleshooting.html)

Finally, your configuration specifies `-keep public class !testAppH23.** { *;}`, which keeps all public classes except those in `testAppH23`, and their public/protected/private class members, from being shrunk/optimized/obfuscated. This may cause some (harmless) notes about descriptor classes. For consistency, you may want to remove "public" for the classes, or add "public protected" for the class members.

Comment: In my case when I've added Dropbox jars and Google Drive jars it helped just adding -dontwarn org.apache.** and -dontwarn com.google.android.gms.** (in addition to proguard-google-api-client.txt added automatically by Google Eclipse plugin). There was no need to add the -dontnote statement. Probably because all warnings have dissapeared and there was no reason to "note" about any issues. Thanks for your post.

Answer (score 2):

You can try to resolve it:

```
-ignorewarnings
```

Answer (score 0):

You should check your strings.xml resources and make equal if exist or add translatable="false"

```
<string name="my_text" translatable="false">Hello World</string>
```