# ProGuard with maven-android-plugin

Tags: java, android, maven, proguard

I'm trying to pack my project to APK and then obfuscate it with ProGuard.

Here is my pom:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.skayred</groupId>
    <artifactId>skayred</artifactId>
    <version>1.26</version>
    <packaging>apk</packaging>
    <name>skayred</name>

<properties>
    <environment>development</environment>
</properties>

<dependencies>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>android</groupId>
        <artifactId>android</artifactId>
        <version>2.2_r3</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.android.maps</groupId>
        <artifactId>maps</artifactId>
        <version>8_r2</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.http-client</groupId>
        <artifactId>google-http-client</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.0-beta</version>
        <exclusions>

            <exclusion>
                <groupId>xpp3</groupId>
                <artifactId>xpp3</artifactId>
            </exclusion>

            <exclusion>
                <groupId>com.google.protobuf</groupId>
                <artifactId>protobuf-java</artifactId>
            </exclusion>

            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
                <artifactId>jackson-core-asl</artifactId>
            </exclusion>

            <exclusion>
                <groupId>junit</groupId>
                <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            </exclusion>

            <exclusion>
                <groupId>commons-codec</groupId>
                <artifactId>commons-codec</artifactId>
            </exclusion>

            <exclusion>
                <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
            </exclusion>

            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
                <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
            </exclusion>

            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
                <artifactId>httpcore</artifactId>
            </exclusion>

            <exclusion>
                <groupId>com.google.code.findbugs</groupId>
                <artifactId>jsr305</artifactId>
            </exclusion>

        </exclusions>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.http-client</groupId>
        <artifactId>google-http-client-extensions-android2</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.0-beta</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>com.google.android</groupId>
                <artifactId>android</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
        <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
        <version>10.0.1</version>

        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>com.google.code.findbugs</groupId>
                <artifactId>jsr305</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>

    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.skyhookwireless.wps</groupId>
        <artifactId>skyhookwireless-wps</artifactId>
        <version>4.2.0.14</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.bugsense.trace</groupId>
        <artifactId>bugsense-trace</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.2</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-jarsigner-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>

        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>junit</groupId>
                <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>

    </dependency>

</dependencies>

<build>
    <finalName>${project.artifactId}</finalName>

    <resources>
        <!-- a pair definition for resource filtering of xml files only (not binary files since they get mangled -->
        <resource>
            <directory>${project.basedir}/res</directory>
            <filtering>true</filtering>
            <targetPath>${project.build.directory}/filtered-res</targetPath>
            <includes>
                <include>**/*.xml</include>
            </includes>
        </resource>
        <resource>
            <directory>${project.basedir}/res</directory>
            <filtering>false</filtering>
            <targetPath>${project.build.directory}/filtered-res</targetPath>
            <excludes>
                <exclude>**/*.xml</exclude>
            </excludes>
        </resource>
    </resources>

    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>initialize</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>resources</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>com.jayway.maven.plugins.android.generation2</groupId>
            <artifactId>android-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0</version>
            <extensions>true</extensions>
            <configuration>
                <resourceDirectory>${project.build.directory}/filtered-res</resourceDirectory>
                <manifest>
                    <debuggable>true</debuggable>
                </manifest>
                <dex>
                    <jvmArguments>
                        <jvmArgument>-Xms256m</jvmArgument>
                        <jvmArgument>-Xmx512m</jvmArgument>
                    </jvmArguments>
                </dex>
                <sdk>
                    <platform>8</platform>
                </sdk>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>manifestUpdate</id>
                    <phase>process-resources</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>manifest-update</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <id>alignApk</id>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>zipalign</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>

</build>

<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>development</id>
        <!-- using this since activeByDefault does not work well with multiple profiles -->
        <activation>
            <property>
                <name>environment</name>
                <value>!production</value>
            </property>
        </activation>
        <properties>
            <deployment.host>http://192.168.192.15:5000</deployment.host>
        </properties>
    </profile>
    <profile>
        <id>production</id>

        <properties>
            <deployment.host>https://somehost.com</deployment.host>
        </properties>
    </profile>
    <profile>
        <id>release</id>
        <properties>
            <deployment.host>https://somehost.com</deployment.host>
        </properties>
        <!-- via this activation the profile is automatically used when the release is done with the maven release
        plugin -->
        <activation>
            <property>
                <name>performRelease</name>
                <value>true</value>
            </property>
        </activation>
        <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-jarsigner-plugin</artifactId>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <id>signing</id>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>sign</goal>
                                <goal>verify</goal>
                            </goals>
                            <phase>package</phase>
                            <inherited>true</inherited>
                            <configuration>
                                <removeExistingSignatures>true</removeExistingSignatures>
                                <archiveDirectory/>
                                <includes>
                                    <include>${project.build.directory}/${project.artifactId}.apk</include>
                                </includes>
                                <keystore>${sign.keystore}</keystore>
                                <alias>${sign.alias}</alias>
                                <storepass>${sign.storepass}</storepass>
                                <keypass>${sign.keypass}</keypass>
                                <verbose>true</verbose>
                            </configuration>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>
                <!-- the signed apk then needs to be zipaligned and we activate proguard and we run the manifest
                update -->
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>com.jayway.maven.plugins.android.generation2</groupId>
                    <artifactId>android-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <inherited>true</inherited>
                    <configuration>
                        <sign>
                            <debug>false</debug>
                        </sign>
                        <zipalign>
                            <verbose>true</verbose>
                            <inputApk>${project.build.directory}/${project.artifactId}.apk</inputApk>
                            <outputApk>${project.build.directory}/${project.artifactId}-signed-aligned.apk
                            </outputApk>
                        </zipalign>
                        <manifest>
                            <debuggable>false</debuggable>
                            <versionCodeAutoIncrement>true</versionCodeAutoIncrement>
                        </manifest>
                        <proguard>
                            <skip>false</skip>
                        </proguard>
                    </configuration>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <id>manifestUpdate</id>
                            <phase>process-resources</phase>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>manifest-update</goal>
                            </goals>
                        </execution>
                        <execution>
                            <id>alignApk</id>
                            <phase>package</phase>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>zipalign</goal>
                            </goals>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                    <artifactId>build-helper-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <configuration>
                        <artifacts>
                            <artifact>
                                <file>${project.build.directory}/${project.artifactId}-signed-aligned.apk</file>
                                <type>apk</type>
                                <classifier>signed-aligned</classifier>
                            </artifact>
                            <artifact>
                                <file>${project.build.directory}/proguard/mapping.txt</file>
                                <type>map</type>
                                <classifier>release</classifier>
                            </artifact>
                        </artifacts>
                    </configuration>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <id>attach-signed-aligned</id>
                            <phase>package</phase>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>attach-artifact</goal>
                            </goals>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>
    </profile>
</profiles>
```

proguard.cfg:

```
-optimizationpasses 5
-dontusemixedcaseclassnames
-dontskipnonpubliclibraryclasses
-dontpreverify
-verbose
-optimizations !code/simplification/arithmetic,!field/*,!class/merging/*

-keep public class * extends android.app.Activity
-keep public class * extends android.app.Application
-keep public class * extends android.app.Service
-keep public class * extends android.content.BroadcastReceiver
-keep public class * extends android.content.ContentProvider
-keep public class * extends android.app.backup.BackupAgentHelper
-keep public class * extends android.preference.Preference
-keep public class com.android.vending.licensing.ILicensingService

-keepclasseswithmembernames class * {
    native <methods>;
}

-keepclasseswithmembers class * {
    public <init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet);
}

-keepclasseswithmembers class * {
    public <init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, int);
}

-keepclassmembers class * extends android.app.Activity {
   public void *(android.view.View);
}

-keepclassmembers enum * {
    public static **[] values();
    public static ** valueOf(java.lang.String);
}

-keep class * implements android.os.Parcelable {
  public static final android.os.Parcelable$Creator *;
}

-renamesourcefileattribute SourceFile
-keepattributes SourceFile,LineNumberTable
```

But when I'm trying to run `mvn3 clean install -Prelease -X`, I've get an error and loooong command. When I'm trying to run that command, I've got:

```
Warning: com.google.common.collect.AbstractBiMap: can't find referenced class javax.annotation.Nullable
Warning: com.google.common.collect.AbstractBiMap: can't find referenced class javax.annotation.Nullable
Note: the configuration refers to the unknown class 'com.android.vending.licensing.ILicensingService'
Note: there were 1 references to unknown classes.
  You should check your configuration for typos.
Warning: there were 1277 unresolved references to classes or interfaces.
     You may need to specify additional library jars (using '-libraryjars'),
     or perhaps the '-dontskipnonpubliclibraryclasses' option.
Warning: there were 6 unresolved references to program class members.
     Your input classes appear to be inconsistent.
     You may need to recompile them and try again.
     Alternatively, you may have to specify the options 
     '-dontskipnonpubliclibraryclasses' and/or
     '-dontskipnonpubliclibraryclassmembers'.
java.io.IOException: Please correct the above warnings first.
at proguard.Initializer.execute(Initializer.java:308)
at proguard.ProGuard.initialize(ProGuard.java:210)
at proguard.ProGuard.execute(ProGuard.java:85)
at proguard.ProGuard.main(ProGuard.java:499)
```

And lots of warning about referencing before. What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: How do you integrate google LVL into your project, as a library project or copy over source code?

Comment: [License Verification Library](http://developer.android.com/guide/publishing/licensing.html)

Comment: I have not integrate it. Is this a reason?

Comment: I suppose, your Proguard is trying to resolve com.android.vending.licensing.ILicensingService which is from LVL, try integrate it to your project (either through jar or source code) or simply completely remove it from your project, and see what you get.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The warnings say that many classes that you are processing refer to classes that aren't present in the input jars or library jars:

- [ProGuard manual > Troubleshooting > Warning: can't find referenced
  class](http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/troubleshooting.html#unresolvedclass)

This is a common problem in Android, where you're processing third party libraries that depend on other, missing libraries (but don't really use them in practice). Some Android-specific questions and answers:

- [Proguard tells me 'Please correct the above warnings first.'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8074417/proguard-tells-me-please-correct-the-above-warnings-first-how-to-address-ref)
- [proguard hell - can't find referenced class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6974231/proguard-hell-cant-find-referenced-class)

The (harmless) note says that your proguard.cfg refers to com.android.vending.licensing.ILicensingService, but that class isn't present in your code. You can remove the line from the configuration.

Comment: Note about LicensingService has dismissed, but exception and warnings stayed.

Comment: I've applyed all the -dontwarn and warning about resolvin disappears too