# Using Proguard to obfuscute java code

Tags: java, android

when trying to create a secure apk using proguard, i have got the following error:

```
Proguard returned with error code 1. See console
[2013-10-19 09:04:44 - TeacherBook] Warning: com.dafruits.android.library.widgets.ExtendedListView: can't find referenced class com.dafruits.android.library.R$styleable
[2013-10-19 09:04:44 - TeacherBook] Warning: com.dafruits.android.library.widgets.ExtendedListView: can't find referenced class com.dafruits.android.library.R$styleable
[2013-10-19 09:04:44 - TeacherBook] Warning: com.dafruits.android.library.widgets.ExtendedListView: can't find referenced class com.dafruits.android.library.R$anim
[2013-10-19 09:04:44 - TeacherBook] Warning: com.dafruits.android.library.widgets.ExtendedListView: can't find referenced class com.dafruits.android.library.R$anim
[2013-10-19 09:04:44 - TeacherBook] Warning: com.dafruits.android.library.widgets.ExtendedListView: can't find referenced class com.dafruits.android.library.R$anim
[2013-10-19 09:04:44 - TeacherBook] Warning: com.dafruits.android.library.widgets.ExtendedListView: can't find referenced class com.dafruits.android.library.R
[2013-10-19 09:04:44 - TeacherBook] Warning: there were 6 unresolved references to classes or interfaces.
[2013-10-19 09:04:44 - TeacherBook]          You may need to add missing library jars or update their versions.
[2013-10-19 09:04:44 - TeacherBook]          If your code works fine without the missing classes, you can suppress
[2013-10-19 09:04:44 - TeacherBook]          the warnings with '-dontwarn' options.
[2013-10-19 09:04:44 - TeacherBook]          (http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/troubleshooting.html#unresolvedclass)
[2013-10-19 09:04:44 - TeacherBook] java.io.IOException: Please correct the above warnings first.
[2013-10-19 09:04:44 - TeacherBook]     at proguard.Initializer.execute(Initializer.java:369)
[2013-10-19 09:04:44 - TeacherBook]     at proguard.ProGuard.initialize(ProGuard.java:212)
[2013-10-19 09:04:44 - TeacherBook]     at proguard.ProGuard.execute(ProGuard.java:87)
[2013-10-19 09:04:44 - TeacherBook]     at proguard.ProGuard.main(ProGuard.java:484)
```

Comment: You may use dontwarn tags at your proguard.cfg: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8074417/proguard-tells-me-please-correct-the-above-warnings-first-how-to-address-ref

Comment: Thanks the problem is now solved.

Comment: Then can you can mark it answer if my comment helped you to solve your problem. This will help anyone with the same problem.